# "TypeError: Cannot read property 'filename' of undefined " while using multer to upload user profile photo

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express, multer

**I am trying to upload user profile photo using express.js server and Multer, but don't know why I am getting "TypeError: Cannot read property 'filename' of undefined" error.
Here below is my code for both server and html.**

**imported packages**

```
   const multer= require('multer');
   const path=require('path');
   const express=require('express');
   const app=express();
   app.use(express.json());
   app.use(cors());
```

**middleware code**

```
      app.use(express.static( __dirname+"./backend/database/"));

      var upload=multer({dest:'public/'});

      var upload=multer({
    storage:multer.diskStorage({
           destination:function(req,file,cb){
              cb(null,'./public');
          },
            filename:(req,file,cb)=>{ cb(null,file.originalname);
         }
       })
    }).single('Image')
```

**API to register user**

```
    app.post('/register',upload,(req,res)=>{
         let userData ={
            Name:req.body.Name,
            Password:req.body.Password,
            Username:req.body.Username,
            ContactNo:req.body.ContactNo,
            Image:req.file.filename
         }
       console.log(req.body);//to check if image successfully recieved from the frontend  
     })
```

**HTML code**

```
     <form [formGroup]="register" (ngSubmit)="Register(register.value)" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
            <legend>
                Sign Up
            </legend>
            <mat-form-field  color="warn">
                <mat-label>Name</mat-label>
                <mat-icon >person</mat-icon>
                <input matInput type="email" formControlName="Username" value="Username" />
            </mat-form-field>
    
            <mat-form-field  color="warn">
                <mat-label>Enter your Email</mat-label> 
                <mat-icon >email</mat-icon>
                <input matInput type="email" formControlName="Name" value="Email" />
            </mat-form-field>
            
            <mat-form-field  color="warn"> 
                <mat-label>Phone Number</mat-label>
                <mat-icon >call</mat-icon>
                <input matInput type="number"  formControlName="ContactNo" placeholder="+91 XXXXXXXXXX"
                    value="ContactNo" />
            </mat-form-field>
    
            <mat-form-field  color="warn">
                <mat-label>Write your Password</mat-label>
                <mat-icon >lock</mat-icon>
                <input matInput formControlName="Password" placeholder="Password" type="password" />
            </mat-form-field>

            <div color="warn">
                <label>Upload Your Photo</label>
                <mat-icon >photo</mat-icon>
                <input class="file"  formControlName="Image" placeholder="Upload Image" type="file" />
            </div>
            <button mat-raised-button color="warn" type="submit" (click)="changeAgain()">submit</button>
            <button mat-raised-button color="primary" style="margin-top: 2px;" type="reset">Reset</button>
            <br>
        </form>
```

**to post the data**

```
     Register(data)
    {
     this.serve.RegisterUser(data);
       //" serve " here is alias for injected HTTP services
    }
```

Comment: Does your middleware works and store files on the server?

Comment: Try testing using ```Postman```, if it works fine then you might be doing something wrong. Also what does the network tab show in the request? Is there any data?

Comment: Thanks, @TayyabFerozi, I tested this in postman and realized the problem was the data format in which I was posting. Actually, I need a little more help from you, could you please guide me on how I can send the form data with one input as an image and other as simple text and number via using the service that I have injected

Comment: looks like you are using angular or some another technology which I am not familiar with, but if it is an asynchronous `xhr`, it is pretty straightforward. You just need to append the field and it's value the same way you might have done with the image `FormData`. e.g.
`const formData = new FormData();`
`formData.append("name", "Tayyab Ferozi");`
`formData.append("age", "17");`
.....Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the error source:

```
      Image:req.file.filename
```

Because you are not setting multer middleware.

```
app.use(multer({ storage: fileStorage, fileFilter }).single("image"));
```

When you set this, multer will attach 'file' object to "req". Currently there `req.file` is undefined